# Webpack: Less Loader with CSS imports not working

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, less

Need to transpile my styles.less file into a CSS bundle to consume on my index page.  I'm under the assumption that the style.less file will be loaded using the less loader and compiled using less.  From that point it will be passed to the css-loader, however it seems to be that the css-loader cannot process less syntax which is what my error is indicating.  I've provided the code, just wondered how I would setup my webpack.config.js file to handle the style.less being piped through multiple loaders.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**style.less**

```
// BOOTSTRAP W RESPONSIVE
@import './../../node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
// MATERIAL DESIGN ICONIC FONT
@import '~material-design-iconic-font/less/material-design-iconic-font.less';
@md-font-path: '~material-design-iconic-font/fonts';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/pnotify/src/pnotify.css';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/select2/select2.css';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/pace-js/themes/blue/pace-theme-center-simple.css';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/jstree/dist/themes/default/style.css';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/bootstrap-touchspin/dist/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.css';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css';
@import (inline) './../../node_modules/bootstrap-tokenfield/dist/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css';
@import "variables.less";   
@import "w-helpers.less";   // Helper Classes
@import 'w-mixins.less';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const validate = require('webpack-validator');
const plugins = require('./plugins');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'js', 'main.js'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'build'),
  style: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'less', 'style.less')
};

const common = {
    entry: {
      app: PATHS.app,
      style: PATHS.style,
      vendor: [
        ....
      ]      
    },
    output: {
      path: PATHS.build,
      filename: '[name].js'  
    },
    target: 'web',
    module: {
      loaders: [             
        { test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
        { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
        { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
        { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},       
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
        { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loader: 'url?limit=10000!img?progressive=true' },
        { test: /(\.tpl|\.html)$/, loader: 'underscore-template-loader' }
      ]
    }, 
    plugins: [     
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\.\/locale$/, 'empty-module', false, /js$/),

      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
        ....
      }),

      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js')
    ], 
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        ....
      }
    }
  }

var config;

// Detect how npm is run and branch based on that
switch(process.env.npm_lifecycle_event) {
  case 'build:dev':
    config = merge(
      plugins.clean(PATHS.build),
      common,
      plugins.extractCSS(PATHS.style),
      { devtool: 'source-map' }     
    );
    break;
  case 'build:prod':
    config = merge( 
      plugins.clean(PATHS.build),
      common,      
      plugins.minify(),
      plugins.extractCSS(PATHS.style)
    );
    break;
  default:
    config = merge(
      plugins.clean(PATHS.build),
      common,
      plugins.extractCSS(PATHS.style),
      { devtool: 'eval-source-map' }      
    );
}

module.exports = validate(config);
```

**plugins.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

exports.extractCSS = function(paths) {
  return {
    module: {
      loaders: [
        // Extract CSS during build
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader', 'less-loader'),
          include: paths
        }
      ]
    },
    postcss: function () {
        return [require('autoprefixer'), require('precss')];
    },
    plugins: [
      // Output extracted CSS to a file
      new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ]
  };
}
```

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./public/less/style.less
Module build failed: Unknown word (1:1)

```
1 | // BOOTSTRAP W RESPONSIVE
  | ^
2 | @import './../../node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
3 |
```

@ ./public/less/style.less 4:14-125

Comment: You sure you're using the `ExtractTextPlugin` correctly? ~ https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin#api. What version of webpack and the plugin are you using?

Comment: It looks like your `ExtractTextPlugin.extract` syntax is wrong.  Shouldn't it be `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader')`?  That's assuming it's the "old" API.  As Phil points out, if it's the new API, it's totally wrong.

Comment: @Phil I'm not on Webpack 2 so the current syntax should be fine

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I was chaining the loaders incorrectly but now I'm running into a different issue, now it cannot resolve images, such as png's and gifs that are not located in the relative path of where my style.less file is located...